# Javascript IndexedDB example encountering transaction and db variable not defined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm learning javascript indexedDB and so, I followed an example from Javascript tutorial - https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-indexeddb/.

I followed the example to understand how it works. Below are my codes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Indexed Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
               if (!window.indexedDB)  {
                   console.log("Your browser doesn't support IndexedDB");
               }
                   const request = indexedDB.open("indexedDatabase", 3);
                   request.onerror = (event) => {
                       console.error ("Database error: ${event.target.errorCode}");
                   };
                   request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                       console.log("success: " + request);

                       insertContact(db, {
                           email: 'john.doe@outlook.com',
                           firstName: 'John',
                           lastName: 'Doe'
                       });

                       insertContact(db, {
                           email: 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
                           firstName: 'Jane',
                           lastName: 'Doe'
                       });
                   };

                   // create the Contacts object store and indexes
                   request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
                       let db = event.target.result;

                       //create the Contacts object store 
                       //with auto-increment id
                       let store = db.createObjectStore('Contacts', {
                           autoIncrement: true
                       });

                       //create an index on the email property
                       let index = store.createIndex('email', 'email', {
                           unique: true
                       });
                   };

                   function insertContact(db, contact) {
                       //create a new transaction
                       const txn = db.transaction('Contacts','readwrite');
                   }

                       //get the Contacts object store
                       const store = txn.objectStore('Contacts');

                       let query = store.put(contact);

                       //handle success case
                       query.onsuccess = function (event) {
                           console.log(event);
                       };

                       //handle the error case
                       query.onerror = function (event) {
                           console.log(event.target.errorCode);
                       }

                       //close the database once the transaction completes
                       txn.oncomplete = function () {
                           db.close();
                       };
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I encountered the following 2 errors which I have spent a lot of time to understand why.

Uncaught ReferenceError: txn is not defined
at indexedStorage.html:53:47

Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined
at request.onsuccess (indexedStorage.html:18:47)

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am following the example from the Javascript tutorial and were expected to insert the two records into the indexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- You placed the `}` ending the insertContact function too early. It needs to wrap the logic for inserting the contact
- You close the database connection as soon as one transaction is done. This will make the second transaction fail - maybe not in this sample (because both transactions will be kicked off simultaneously) but it'll be a surprise if you ever do anything else with the code.

  ```
  function insertContact(db, contact) {
      //create a new transaction
      const txn = db.transaction('Contacts','readwrite');

      // Moved the } from here...

      //get the Contacts object store
      const store = txn.objectStore('Contacts');

      let query = store.put(contact);

      //handle success case
      query.onsuccess = function (event) {
          console.log(event);
      };

      //handle the error case
      query.onerror = function (event) {
          console.log(event.target.errorCode);
      }

      //close the database once the transaction completes
      txn.oncomplete = function () {
          // You probably don't want to do this:
          // db.close();
      };
  }   // ...to here
  ```

Comment: Thank you Joshua Bell for your kind advice. I understand the concept already. But I have a new issue. Instead of appending new record into IndexedDB, it overwrote the existing record. I am still trying to troubleshoot. if I can't manage to resolve, I will post in this forum again.